# show sum on first record crystal report

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, crystal-reports, report

I want to show sum all bank just in the first record

```
if  {?bank1} = {Customer.CustomerSay} then {#1} else  0
if  {?bank2} = {Customer.CustomerSay} then {#2} else 0
if  {?bank3} = {Customer.CustomerSay} then {#3} else  0
...

if  {?bank6} = {Customer.CustomerSay} then {#6} else  0
```

I have 6 banks.

Show in each record the sum of the bank itself.

But I want to show sum all bank in the first record.

How can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just make a new group including all your banks (for example on your bank ID).
This will give you the possibility to display a header band and a footer.
You can put the sum in the header.
Take care to put the column headers before.